# What are OLTP and OLAP. What is the difference between them?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, olap, oltp

Actually what do they mean? All articles I find about them don't give me an idea, or my knowledge is too insufficient to understand it.

Will some one give me some resources with which I can learn this from scratch.

Comment: Refer to http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html to get started and then just Google around for more links about details and differences

Comment: Ok so simple DB operations are in OLTP category And complex large data processing is in OLAP, Thats the Base concept right ??

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy yeah insert,update,delete will deal with OLTP

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy You should really put more initial effort into researching a topic. The two resources provided by Nagaraj S's answer were literally the top two pages returned by google. You're cheating yourself out of knowledge when you let someone else do the work for you. For tips on writing better SO questions, consult the [SO help page: How to Ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 435, accepted):

Here you will find a better solution [OLTP vs. OLAP](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html)

- **OLTP** (On-line Transaction Processing) is involved in the operation of a particular system. OLTP is characterized by a large number of short on-line transactions (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). The main emphasis for OLTP systems is put on very fast query processing, maintaining data integrity in multi-access environments and an effectiveness measured by number of transactions per second. In OLTP database there is detailed and current data, and schema used to store transactional databases is the entity model (usually 3NF). It involves Queries accessing individual record like Update your Email in Company database.
- **OLAP** (On-line Analytical Processing) deals with Historical Data or Archival Data. OLAP is characterized by relatively low volume of transactions. Queries are often very complex and involve aggregations. For OLAP systems a response time is an effectiveness measure. OLAP applications are widely used by Data Mining techniques. In OLAP database there is aggregated, historical data, stored in multi-dimensional schemas (usually star schema). Sometime query need to access large amount of data in Management records like what was the profit of your company in last year.

Comment: Very clear information. Thank you for sharing it helped me clear my doubts.

Comment: What does the "OL" refer to?

Comment: If others need a refresher as well: [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) is a normal form that is used in normalizing a database design to reduce the duplication of data and ensure referential integrity

Comment: OL refers to "ONLINE", which means completion of data processing in real time and not batch-processing.

Answer (score 269):

**Very short answer :**

Different databases have different uses. I'm not a database expert.
Rule of thumb:

- if you are doing analytics (ex. aggregating historical data) use OLAP
- if you are doing transactions (ex. adding/removing orders on an e-commerce cart) use OLTP

**Short answer:**

Let's consider two example scenarios:

*Scenario 1:*

You are building an online store/website, and you want to be able to:

- store user data, passwords, previous transactions...
- store actual products, their associated prices

You want to be able to find data for a particular user, change its name... basically perform INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE operations on user data. Same with products, etc.

You want to be able to make transactions, possibly involving a user buying a product (that's a relation). Then OLTP is probably a good fit.

*Scenario 2:*

You have an online store/website, and you want to compute things like

- the "total money spent by all users"
- "what is the most sold product"

This falls into the analytics/business intelligence domain, and therefore OLAP is probably more suited.

If you think in terms of "It would be nice to know how/what/how much"..., and that involves all "objects" of one or more kind (ex. all the users and most of the products to know the total spent) then OLAP is probably better suited.

**Longer answer:**

Of course things are not so simple. That's why we have to use short tags like `OLTP`and `OLAP` in the first place. Each database should be evaluated independently in the end.

So what could be the fundamental difference between OLAP and OLTP?

Well, databases have to store data somewhere. It shouldn't be surprising that the way the data is stored heavily reflects the possible use of said data. Data is usually stored on a hard drive.
Let's think of a hard drive as a really wide sheet of paper, where we can read and write things. There are two ways to organize our reads and writes so that they can be efficient and fast.

**One way** is to make a book that is a bit like a *phone book*. On each page of the book, we store the information regarding a particular user. Now that's nice, we can find the information for a particular user very easily! Just jump to the page! We can even have a special page at the beginning to tell us on which page the users are if we want.
But on the other hand, if we want to find, say, how much money all of our users spent then we would have to read every page, i.e. the whole book!
That would be a row-based book/database (OLTP). The optional page at the beginning would be the index.

**Another way** to use our big sheet of paper is to make an *accounting book*. I'm no accountant, but let's imagine that we would have a page for "expenditures", "purchases"... That's nice because now we can query things like "give me the total revenue" very quickly (just read the "purchases" page). We can also ask for more involved things like "give me the top ten products sold" and still have acceptable performance.
But now consider how painful it would be to find the expenditures for a particular user. You would have to go through the whole list of everyone's expenditures and filter the ones of that particular user, then sum them. Which basically amounts to "read the whole book" again.
That would be a column-based database (OLAP).

**It follows that**:

- `OLTP` databases are meant to be used to do many small transactions, and usually serve as a "single source of truth".
- `OLAP` databases on the other hand are more suited for analytics, data mining, fewer queries but they are usually bigger (they operate on more data).

It's a bit more involved than that of course and that's a 20 000 feet overview of how databases differ, but it allows me not to get lost in a sea of acronyms.

Speaking of acronyms:

- OLTP = Online transaction processing
- OLAP = Online analytical processing

To read a bit further, here are some relevant links which heavily inspired my answer:

- http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html
- http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/Blogs/You-and-i/Archive/db-102-database-orientation-row-vs-column/
- http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DataLake.html

Comment: nice approach using different levels of explanation, accessible language and with concrete examples. a model for people answering questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: "When in doubt, I just use SQL." - SQL is a language and this doesn't answer the question. There's all kinds of data mgmt systems that know how interpret SQL and to translate it for working with all kinds of datasources behind the hood. One can make sql queries even on spark dataframes. That's like saying "when in doubt, I just use html" . Ok, it is the short answer but it's silly

Comment: @RaduSimionescu I agree. The intent here is to encourage the inexperienced programmer reading this to experiment. I couldn't think of a better wording - suggestions welcome!

Comment: @RaduSimionescu is right on. I fell from my chair on at least 2 occasions, reading yr answer. The fact you garnered many upvotes doesn't mean that yr answer cannot be perfected, something you seem to be aware of. My two suggestions to significantly improve yr answer at a very small cost are: (a) suppress the "Very short answer" section. Anybody knowing about DBs would choke on such abuse of fundamental concepts and semantics. (b) you do it again in _"Then OLTP is probably a good fit (think SQL databases)."_ Either suppress that again, or at the very least write "(think schema-based DBs)." HTH.

Comment: @Cbhihe thanks for the suggestions. What about short answer: “rule of thumb - it you are doing analytics (ex. aggregating historical data) use OLAP, otherwise if you are doing transactions (ex. adding/removing orders on an e-commerce cart) use OLTP” ? I am not sure what "Then OLTP is probably a good fit (think schema-based DBs)."  would improve here - I am actually considering removing “think SQL databases”.

Comment: Yes, what you propose would be an improvement, on both counts. It would not do justice to the topic of course, but that is beside the point. Cheers !

Comment: "if you are doing analytics [...] use OLAP" - that is phrased badly. If you are doing analytics, then your automatically doing OLAP. OLAP / OLTP is a characterization of query types by their use case. Similarly, there are systems built to support those use cases / query types. OLAP is not something concrete, but abstract. It's a bit like saying "if you're programming, use a programming language".

Answer (score 25):

The difference is quite simple:

**OLTP (Online Transaction Processing)**

OLTP is a class of information systems that facilitate and manage transaction-oriented applications. OLTP has also been used to refer to processing in which the system responds immediately to user requests. Online transaction processing applications are high throughput and insert or update-intensive in database management. Some examples of OLTP systems include order entry, retail sales, and financial transaction systems.

**OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)**

OLAP is part of the broader category of business intelligence, which also encompasses relational database, report writing and data mining. Typical applications of OLAP include business reporting for sales, marketing, management reporting, business process management (BPM), budgeting and forecasting, financial reporting and similar areas.

See more details [OLTP and OLAP](http://www.examplesofsql.com/oltp-and-olap-data-mining/)

Answer (score 8):

OLTP: It stands for OnLine Transaction Processing and is used for managing current day to day data information.
OLAP: It stands for OnLine Analytical Processing and is used to maintain the past history of data and mainly used for data analysis, it can also be referred to as warehouse.