# Difference between RDS and Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

Can anyone list down the main differences between Amazon Redshift and RDS? I know both are relational DB's but why choose one over the other ?

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900185/what-are-oltp-and-olap-what-is-the-difference-between-them

Answer (score 5):

RDS is a managed service for Online Transaction Processing databases (OLTP), i.e. a managed service for the usual MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MariaDB, Microsoft SQL Server or Aurora (Amazon's own relational database)

Redshift is a managed service for data warehousing, i.e. columnar oriented storage, typical for business analytics type of workloads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your usecase.

Put it in example:

If you use `Select * from <table>` more often, go for RDS. (OLTP)

If you use features like `SUM(A)` more often, go for RedShift. (OLAP)

Answer (score -1):

**Brief Introduction of AWS RDS & Redshift,**
**AWS RDS:**
Amazon RDS is a managed relational database service that provides you six familiar database engines to choose from, including Amazon Aurora, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and PostgreSQL. This means that the code, applications, and tools you already use today with your existing databases can be used with Amazon RDS. Amazon RDS handles routine database tasks such as provisioning, patching, backup, recovery, failure detection, and repair.

**AWS Redshift:**
Amazon Redshift is a fast and powerful, fully managed, petabyte-scale data warehouse service in the cloud. Traditional data warehouses require significant time and resource to administer, especially for large datasets. In addition, the financial cost associated with building, maintaining, and growing self-managed, on-premise data warehouses is very high. Amazon Redshift not only significantly lowers the cost of a data warehouse, but also makes it easy to analyze large amounts of data very quickly.