# How to stream real time data from aws kinesis to react based frontend

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have a use-case wherein I need to stream a 100GB+ data to the frontend in graphical format, I am using AWS kinesis for same.

I know the theory part wherein I can have an intermediate server with WebSockets to deal with real-time data on the frontend, I need some tutorials or blogs which can guide and help in depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an intermediate storage between stream and frontend. The intermediate storage solution can be aws redshift.

**Steps**

1. Connect stream destination to aws redshift: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/streaming-events-from-amazon-pinpoint-to-redshift/
2. If required, perform analysis on data and store it in a redshift table.
3. Based on your use case query data from redshift or move the data to aws RDS and then fetch it from front end. [Difference between RDS and Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710527/difference-between-rds-and-redshift).

This is one of the approach, but you want real time data in react front end, here what you can do is connect stream to redshift and poll for the data. Do read about redshift connection and query limit.

Comment: I am trying to get someone to answer the question linked below for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226785/how-do-i-store-aws-pinpoint-messages-to-rds