# what does "Online" in Online analytical processing means?

Tags: database, architecture, olap

Is there any `offline analytical processing`? If there is, what is the difference with `online analytical processing`?

In [What are OLTP and OLAP. What is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900185/what-are-oltp-and-olap-what-is-the-difference-between-them), OLAP is `deals with Historical Data or Archival Data. OLAP is characterized by relatively low volume of transactions. Queries are often very complex and involve aggregations.`

I don't understand what does the word `online` in `online analytical processing` mean?
Is it related to `real time processing`(About `real-time` understanding: `In a short time after the data is generated, this data can be analyzed.` Am I wrong with this understanding)?

When does the **analysis** happen?
I imagine a design like this:
log generated in many apps -> kafka -> (relational DB) -> flink as ETL -> HBase, and the **analysis** will happen after data is inserted into HBase. Is this correct?

If yes, why is it called `online`?
If no, when does **analysis** happen? Please correct me if this design is usually not in the industry.

**P.S. Assuming that the log generated by the apps in a day has a PB level**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: as far as I can tell "Online" appears to stem from characteristics of a scenario where handling transactions with satellite devices (ATM's) was a [new thing](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2796575/oltp-takes-a-bow.html).

**Long version**

To understand what "online" in OLTP means, you have to go back to when ATM's first came out in the 1990s.

If you're a bank in the 1990s, you've got two types of system: your central banking system (i.e. mainframe), and these new fangled ATM's connected to it... online.

So if you're a bank, and someone wants to get money out, you have to do a balance check; and if cash is withdrawn you need to do a debit.  That last action - or transaction - is key, because you don't want to miss that - you want to update your central record back in the bank's central systems.  So that's the transactional processing (TP) part.

The OL part just refers to the remote / satellite / connected devices that participate in the transaction processing.

OLTP is all about making sure that happens reliably.

Comment: Thank you for providing this point of view. I don't know the history of 1990, but I accept the definition of online for the time being.
Because I am learning streaming(e.g. flink), I used to think that "online" would be related to the use or non-use of the database.